# How to validated multiplicate number in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

i am trying to post form with number as 5 or 10 or 15 or 20 like multiplication table of 5

i want to validated if user enter 4 or 3 or 2 or 1 return error if user enter 5 or 10 request accept and go to next

i really can't find on google something like this

here is key and value

```
{
   "1":"100",
   "2":"0",
   "3":"0",
   "4":"0",
   "5":"0",
   "6":"0",
   "7":"0",
   "8":"300",
   "9":"0",
   "10":"0",
   "11":"0",
   "12":"0",
   "13":"0",
   "14":"0",
   "15":"0",
   "16":"0",
   "17":"0",
   "18":"0",
   "19":"0",
   "20":"0",
   "21":"0",
   "22":"0",
   "23":"0",
   "24":"0",
   "25":"0",
   "26":"0",
   "27":"0",
   "28":"0",
   "29":"0",
   "30":"0",
   "31":"0",
   "32":"0",
   "33":"0",
   "34":"0",
   "35":"0",
   "36":"0",
   "37":"0",
   "38":"0",
   "39":"0",
   "40":"0",
   "41":"0",
   "42":"0",
   "43":"0",
   "44":"0",
   "45":"0",
   "46":"0",
   "47":"0",
   "48":"0",
   "49":"0",
   "50":"0",
   "51":"0",
   "52":"0",
   "53":"0",
   "54":"0",
   "55":"0",
   "56":"0",
   "57":"0",
   "58":"0",
   "59":"0",
   "60":"0",
   "61":"0",
   "62":"0",
   "63":"0",
   "64":"0",
   "65":"0",
   "66":"0",
   "67":"0",
   "68":"0",
   "69":"0",
   "70":"0",
   "71":"0",
   "72":"0",
   "73":"0",
   "74":"0",
   "75":"0",
   "76":"0",
   "77":"0",
   "78":"0",
   "79":"0",
   "80":"0",
   "81":"0",
   "82":"0",
   "83":"0",
   "84":"0",
   "85":"0",
   "86":"0",
   "87":"0",
   "88":"0",
   "89":"0",
   "90":"0",
   "91":"0",
   "92":"0",
   "93":"0",
   "94":"0",
   "95":"0",
   "96":"0",
   "97":"0",
   "98":"0",
   "99":"0",
   "100":"0"
}
```

Comment: Are you sending data as form data or json ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#using-closures) to validate a field, i.e:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'my_number' => [
        'required',
        'integer',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if ($value % 5 !== 0) {
                $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');
            }
        },
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Perfect Thank for help